# What's the difference between find_package(MPI) and FindMPI?

Tags: cmake, mpi

As stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindMPI.html)  for CMake 3.0, `find_package(MPI)` and `FindMPI` seem to be interchangeable? But my questions are:

- What are the differences between these two?
- Is that also the case for the latest version?
- Also, does `FindMPI` provide anything similar to the option `REQUIRED` in `find_package()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`FindMPI`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMPI.html) is one of the [Find Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) provided by the CMake installation, the `find_package(MPI)` and `include(FindMPI)` calls are essentially equivalent. (The `include()` is required here to load the module; simply writing `FindMPI` in a CMake file will result in an error.)

The `find_package()` command has two modes: `MODULE` and `CONFIG`. The default is `MODULE` mode, and from the [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#basic-signature-and-module-mode) documentation:

> In Module mode, CMake searches for a file called `Find<PackageName>.cmake`. The file is first searched in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, then among the Find Modules provided by the CMake installation.

Therefore, `find_package(MPI)` will search for a file called `FindMPI.cmake`, which is equivalent to the command `include(FindMPI)`. This holds up, unless you have another `FindMPI.cmake` file defined in your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

While they essentially equivalent commands, calling `find_package()` is typically more useful, as it lets you pass arguments, such as `REQUIRED`, to further specify how the settings of the external project are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to figure it out. `find_package()` and `FindMPI` are two different things.
While `find_package()` is a CMake scripting command, `FindMPI` is a CMake Module.

As stated in the [documentation of `find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/find_package.html), one can select the "Module" mode by which it searches for packages. That means, when one calls `find_package(MPI)`, it will make use of the `FindMPI` module (written in the `FindMPI.cmake` file) to search for the MPI library.

Similar things when you try to find other packages, all of which are listed [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html#find-modules).